# Accessing results of max aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am doing a max aggregation on a numeric field in elasticsearch as follows:

```
SearchResponse sr = client
                .prepareSearch("test")
                .setTypes("test")
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
                .addAggregation(
                        AggregationBuilders.max("id").field(
                                "id")).execute().actionGet();
```

How do I access the max.value returned in java? I could see an example only for terms aggregation. Please help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try the following code,**

```
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.metrics.max.Max;
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.Aggregation;

//process ES Response, it will iterate only once though
// sr = searchResponse
for (Aggregation maxAggs : sr.getAggregations()) {
              Max max = (Max) maxAggs;
              double maxValue = max.getValue();
              System.out.println("maxValue => " + maxValue);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be some efficient way to retrieve the results without looping. Thanks a lot for your reply though.Will use this.

Comment: @RabiyaAshruff I've been using the same api for about a year :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonPath to directly get the aggregation value. first add JsonPath maven dependency in your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

then use below code which will return String :

```
JsonPath.read(sr.toString(), "$.aggregations.id.value")
```

you can get more info about JSONPath from [here](http://code.google.com/p/json-path/)